# how do i dynamically shift the positions of two horizontal divs with jquery animation

Tags: javascript, css

Here is the fiddle of what i got from one tutorial website -

```
http://jsfiddle.net/3U8DP/
```

what i am trying to acheive is that the container I have the article in should be at the beginning of the frame, and as soon as you hover over the button provided in the top-left corner in the fiddle, the article contenct should slide towards right to make room for the sidebar, that is the sidebar should slide in from left pushing the article contents. Now i tried using the

```
$('#hs-menu').hide();
        $('#dummy').hover(function (){
            $('#hs-menu').show(500);
        });
        $('#hs-container').click(function(){$('#hs-menu').hide(500);});
```

but wasnt able to achieve what i aimed. But got only that it still leaves space when i not visible, so how do i fix this please help

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken, what you're aiming for is this:

```
$('#dummy').hover(function (){
  $('#hs-menu').show(500);
  $('#gn-menu').animate({
    left: '200px'
  }, 500);
});
```

and also set your navigation menu's "top" to 0px

```
.hs-menu{top: 0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VMgG2/